# sql query - difference between the row values of same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can anybody tell me how to calculate the difference between the rows of the same column?

```
ID   DeviceID      Reading       Date         Flag
1       2           10          12/02/2015      1
2       3           08          12/02/2015      1
3       2           12          12/02/2015      1
4       2           20          12/02/2015      0
5       4           10          12/02/2015      0
6       2           19          12/02/2015      0
```

In ABOVE table I want to calculate the difference between the Readings for DeviceID 2 for some date say 12/02/2015 for example,
    (12-10=2)
    (20-12=8)
    (19-2 =-1) and want to sum up this difference 
i.e. 2+8+(-1)=9

Comment: Which DBMS you are  using ?

Comment: Two clarifying questions: 1. Could you please add the output you're trying to get? 2. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Add some desired output ..ie what you want here?

Comment: I am using MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS Access, I was try this code for your question:
I was made 4 query in MS Access:
Query1 to get data deviceId=2 and date=12/2/2015:

```
select id, reading from table1 where deviceid=2 and date=#12/2/2015#;
```

Then I make Query2 to get row number from query1:

```
select 
(select count(*) from query1 where a.id>=id) as rowno,
a.reading from query1 a;
```

Then I make Query3 to get difference value field reading from query2:

```
select
(tbl2.reading-tbl1.reading) as diff
from query2 tbl1
left join query2 tbl2 on tbl1.rowno=tbl2.rowno-1
```

And then final query to get sum from result difference in query3:

```
SELECT sum(diff) as Total_Diff
FROM Query3;
```

But, if you use SQL Server, you can use this query (look for example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d870/7)):

```
;with tbl as(
select row_number()over(order by id) as rowno, 
 reading
from table1
where deviceid=2 and date='20150212'
)
select sum(diff) as sum_diff
from (
select 
(b.reading-a.reading) as diff
from tbl a
left join tbl b on a.rowno=b.rowno-1
) tbl_diff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (replace Table1 with your table name):

```
SELECT  Sum([Diffs].[Difference]) AS FinalReading
FROM (
        SELECT IDs.DeviceID, [Table1].Reading AS NextReading, Table1_1.Reading AS PrevReading, [Table1].Reading-Table1_1.Reading AS Difference
        FROM (
                (
                    SELECT      [Table1].DeviceID,
                                [Table1].ID,
                                CLng(Nz(DMax("ID","Table1","[DeviceID] = " & [DeviceID] & " And [ID] < " & [ID]),0)) AS PrevID
                    FROM        Table1
                    WHERE       DeviceID = 2
                )  AS IDs
                INNER JOIN Table1
                ON IDs.ID=[Table1].ID)
                INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1
                ON IDs.PrevID=Table1_1.ID
            )  AS Diffs;
```

The IDs table expression calculates the prev ID for the DeviceID in question.  (I put the WHERE clause in this table expression, but you can move it to the outer one if you want to calc the FinalReadings for ALL devices at once, the filter it at the end.  Less efficient but more flexible.)  We join back to the original tables on the ID and PrevIDs from the inner table expressions, get their Reading values, and perform the difference operation in the Diffs table expression.  The final outer query just sums the Difference values from each row value.